# Issues with breadcrumbs woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I was working around my site and noticed a weird thing - the breadcrumbs appear to have an empty space with no name - Home  /    /  Cases

[image: Issue with breadcrumbs woocommerce]

I tried adding this bit of code to my breadcrumbs.php file, since i found an article that said that this would fix it, but there seems to be no luck

```
if ( empty( $crumb[0] ) ) {
        continue;
    }
```

The categories are fine, the Cases is a root product category, so i'm not quite sure what the problem could be. Did anyone encounter something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include enough code to understand how these variables are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this

```
if ( ! empty( $breadcrumb ) ) {

echo $wrap_before;

foreach ( $breadcrumb as $key => $crumb ) {

    if ( empty( $crumb[0] ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    echo $before;

    if ( ! empty( $crumb[1] ) && sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $crumb[1] ) . '">' . esc_html( $crumb[0] ) . '</a>';
    } else {
        echo esc_html( $crumb[0] );
    }

    echo $after;

    if ( sizeof( $breadcrumb ) !== $key + 1 ) {
        echo $delimiter;
    }
}

echo $wrap_after;

}
```

instead of

```
if ( empty( $crumb[0] ) ) {
continue;
}
```